# Python filtering the type of event in contact

Tags: events, python

I am building a python app that is listening to events from a contract. The issue is that I have different events in only one contract, let me explain.

Currently my code is :

```
def handle_event(event):
    receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(event['transactionHash'])
    result_event1 = contract.events._Event1().processReceipt(receipt)
    result_event2 = contract.events._Event2().processReceipt(receipt)

    if len(result_event1) == 1:
        event_args1 = result_event1[0]['args']

    if len(result_event2) == 1:
        event_args2 = result_event2[0]['args']


def log_loop(event_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
            handle_event(event)
            time.sleep(poll_interval)


def main():
    block_filter = w3.eth.filter({'fromBlock': 'latest', 'address': address})
    log_loop(block_filter, 2)
```

To know which event was run, I need to check for each event if I have any result.

Is there a way to get directly the event that triggers all my code, and so have only 1 line to do that? Because if I need to do if/else for each event, it can be really long if I have 10-20 or more events.

Thanks.